# Laravel Eloquent: JSON comparison

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following model:

[image]

`info` is a JSON be and the results would look something like this:

```json
{
  "cas": "none",
  "uom": "6",
  "url": "http://www.foobar.com",
  "size": "10.00",
  "type": "Chemical",
  "unit": {
    "id": "6",
    "name": "gram",
    "plural": "grams",
    "abbreviation": "g",
    "display_order": "6",
    "additional_aliases": "gr, gm"
  },
  "owner": null,
  "vendor": "Sigma Aldrich",
  "quantity": 8,
  "product_name": "Nafion(R), trimethylsilylated",
  "catalog_number": "392928-10G",
  "ghs_pictograms": [
    1
  ],
  "low_level_warning": 3,
  "high_level_warning": 7
}
```

`info.quantity` tells us how much of this item is left in inventory.

`info.low_level_warning` / `info.high_level_warning` is a user entered value where we want to filter by.

So I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```php
} else if ($filters['filter'] === 'show_below_min_threshold') {
    $query->where(function ($query) {
        return $query->where('info->quantity', '<', 'info->low_level_warning');
    });
} else if ($filters['filter'] === 'show_above_max_threshold') {
    $query->where(function ($query) {
        return $query->where('info->quantity', '>', 'info->high_level_warning');
    });
}
```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How do you know it does not work? What are you getting back?

Comment: @matiaslauriti, well in the above example, if I filter for `show_above_max_threshold`, I should see that example. I get nothing back

Comment: do you have in your model `protected $casts = ['info'=> 'object'];`?

Comment: Yes: `    protected $casts = [
        'info'              => 'array',
        'freezer_locations' => 'array',
    ];
`. The column can be updated fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing two columns. `where` is for comparing a column to a value.

`where('info->quantity', '<', 'info->low_level_warning')` is trying to find rows where `info->>quantity` is less than the string `"info->low_level_warning"`, which doesn't make much sense.

You should use `whereColumn`

```php
} else if ($filters['filter'] === 'show_below_min_threshold') {
    $query->whereColumn('info->quantity', '<', 'info->low_level_warning');
} else if ($filters['filter'] === 'show_above_max_threshold') {
    $query->whereColumn('info->quantity', '>', 'info->high_level_warning');
}
```